# How to extract string if delimiter exist in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the following example of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Path':['Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_LEAD', 'Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_PM','Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_QA', 'Main\Customer1\Project1\DEV',
                         'Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_LEAD', 'Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_PM','Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_SA', 'Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\DEV']})
```

I would like to extract string after delimiter, which is `_` in this case, but there are some rows that `_` does not exist.

The result that I expect is

[image]

Could you please suggest?

Comment: Split on \. Take the last part. Split on `_` . Take the last again.

Comment: The split will still happen. They will form one element arrays. Jst take the alst out of that which will be the first. Eg. `DEV.split("_")` will give `["DEV"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split` and keep the last item:

```
df['Role'] = df['Path'].str.split(r'[_\\]').str[-1]
print(df)

# Output
                                     Path  Role
0    Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_LEAD  LEAD
1      Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_PM    PM
2      Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_QA    QA
3             Main\Customer1\Project1\DEV   DEV
4  Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_LEAD  LEAD
5    Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_PM    PM
6    Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_SA    SA
7           Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\DEV   DEV
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `extract`, since your target strings are caps and are at the end of the string:

```py
df.assign(Role =  df.Path.str.extract(r"([A-Z]+)$"))

                                     Path  Role
0    Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_LEAD  LEAD
1      Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_PM    PM
2      Main\Customer1\Project1\Project_QA    QA
3             Main\Customer1\Project1\DEV   DEV
4  Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_LEAD  LEAD
5    Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_PM    PM
6    Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\Project_SA    SA
7           Main\Customer1\ProjectSAS\DEV   DEV
```